# De-Obfuscating/unminifying a JS code [not duplicate]

Tags: obfuscation, deobfuscation, javascript

I have come across a lot of similar questions on the same heading but unfortunately, none of them provided me with the intended results.

I have a piece of code which, initially I am trying to understand if it is obfuscated or not in the first place. I am also wondering if this is minified.

I reverse-engineered a .wxapkg file and found several files within it - HTML, CSS, JS, JSON. I am trying to perform static analysis on these JS files but I am not able to read them properly.

Previous questions had various tools to de obfuscate but none of them worked for me. There are around 20 JS files which are way too big for each app and all of them are more or less like this. I have provided just a small piece of code from the whole JS file which is as follows (forget the bracket counts):

```
onShareAppMessage: function () {
              var t = "yb_cy/shop/goods?storeId="
                .concat(this.storeId, "&userId=")
                .concat(this.uId);
              return this.util.mpShare({
                t: this.sjxx.storeInfo.name,
                p: t,
              });
            },
          };
        e.default = p;
      }.call(this, o("543d").default));
    },
    ab88: function (t, e, o) {
      (function (t) {
        function e(t) {
          return t && t.__esModule ? t : { default: t };
        }
        o("f00a"), e(o("66fd")), t(e(o("493a")).default);
      }.call(this, o("543d").createPage));
    },
  },
  [["ab88", "common/runtime", "common/vendor"]],
]);
```

Now is this obfuscated? Is this type of code valid for static analysis?
If this is obfuscated, how can I further proceed with the same code?

Are there any easier ways to make it more readable/understandable?

Would be very glad if this is not being downvoted/disregarded and someone genuinely help me with my query :)

Thanks

Note: It was very clumsy before. So I used VS Code's Prettier Code Formatter Extension to make it look like this.